# sign in using twitter into android app using phonegap

Tags: android, twitter, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phonegap and really tried almost every thing to get a proper documentation on twitter sign in using phonegap android but I cant get anything to work. I also tried to make work twitter plugin in github, but that too doesnt have any proper documentation and as I read ,I understood that it was based on phonegap 2.0.0. I am using the latest phonegap 2.9.0 . Someone please help me